# Keras time series prediction with CNN+LSTM model and TimeDistributed layer wrapper

Tags: python, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have several data files of human activity recognition data consisting of time-ordered rows of recorded raw samples. Each row has 8 columns of EMG sensor data and 1 corresponding column of target sensor data. I'm trying to feed the 8 channels of EMG sensor data into a CNN+LSTM deep model in order to predict the 1 channel of target data. I do this by breaking down a dataset (**a** in the image below) into 50-row windows of raw samples (**b** in the image below) and then reshaping these windows into blocks of 4 windows, to act as time steps for the LSTM part of the model (**c** in the image below). The following image will hopefully explain it better:

[image]

I've been following the tutorial here as to how to implement my model: https://medium.com/smileinnovation/how-to-work-with-time-distributed-data-in-a-neural-network-b8b39aa4ce00

I have reshaped the data and built the model but keep coming back to the following error that I cannot figure out how to resolve:

```
    "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected FC_out to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (808, 50, 1)"
```

My code follows and is written in Python using Keras and Tensorflow:

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
    from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
    from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

    #Code that reads in file data and shapes it into 4-window blocks omitted. That code produces the following arrays:
    #x_train  - shape of (808, 4, 50, 8) which equates to (samples, time steps, window length, number of channels)
    #x_valid  - shape of (223, 4, 50, 8) which equates to the same as x_train
    #y_train  - shape of (808, 50, 1) which equates to (samples, window length, number of target channels)


    # Followed machine learning mastery style for ease of reading
    numSteps = x_train.shape[1]
    windowLength = x_train.shape[2]
    numChannels = x_train.shape[3]
    numOutputs = 1

    # Reshape x data for use with TimeDistributed wrapper, adding extra dimension at the end
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], numSteps, windowLength, numChannels, 1)
    x_valid = x_valid.reshape(x_valid.shape[0], numSteps, windowLength, numChannels, 1)


    # Build model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation=activation, name="Conv2D_1"), 
                                     input_shape=(numSteps, windowLength, numChannels, 1)))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation=activation, name="Conv2D_2")))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4, name="CNN_Drop_01"))

    # Flatten for passing to LSTM layer
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(name="Flatten_1")))

    # LSTM and Dropout
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(28, return_sequences=True, name="LSTM_01"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4, name="Drop_01"))

    # Second LSTM and Dropout
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(28, return_sequences=False, name="LSTM_02"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3, name="Drop_02"))

    # Fully Connected layer and further Dropout
    model.add(Dense(16, activation=activation, name="FC_1"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4)) # For example, for 3 outputs classes 

    # Final fully Connected layer specifying outputs
    model.add(Dense(numOutputs, activation=activation, name="FC_out"))

    # Compile model, produce summary and save model image to file
    # NOTE: coeffDetermination refers to a function for calculating R2 and is not included in this code
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics=[coeffDetermination])


    # Now train the model
    history_cb = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid), epochs=30, batch_size=64)
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can figure out what I've done wrong. Or am I just going about this the incorrect way, with trying to use this model configuration for time series prediction?

Answer (score 3):

"ValueError: Error when checking target: expected FC_out to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (808, 50, 1)"

- Your input is (808, 4, 50, 8, 1) and output is (808, 50, 1)
- However, from the model.summary() shows that output shape should be (None, 4, 1)
- Since the # of time steps is 4, y_train should be something like (808, 4, 1).
- Or, if you want to have (888, 50, 1), you need to change model to get the last part as (None, 50, 1).

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_18 (TimeDis (None, 4, 48, 6, 64)      640       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_19 (TimeDis (None, 4, 46, 4, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
CNN_Drop_01 (Dropout)        (None, 4, 46, 4, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_20 (TimeDis (None, 4, 11776)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
LSTM_01 (LSTM)               (None, 4, 28)             1322160   
_________________________________________________________________
Drop_01 (Dropout)            (None, 4, 28)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
Drop_02 (Dropout)            (None, 4, 28)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
FC_1 (Dense)                 (None, 4, 16)             464       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 4, 16)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
FC_out (Dense)               (None, 4, 1)              17        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,360,209
Trainable params: 1,360,209
Non-trainable params: 0
```

For Many to many sequence prediction with different sequence length, check this link https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6063

```
dataX or input : (nb_samples, nb_timesteps, nb_features) -> (1000, 50, 1)
dataY or output: (nb_samples, nb_timesteps, nb_features) -> (1000, 10, 1)

model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))  
model.add(RepeatVector(10))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))   
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```